# Нужна ли запятая перед "чем"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

У меня чуть больше(,) чем через месяц начнётся учёба.

Т. к. сравнение в данном случае отсутствует, то "больше(,) чем" не будет являться сравнительным оборотом, а значит, постановка запятой не требуется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*У меня чуть **больше чем** через месяц начнётся учёба.*

Вы правы, запятая не требуется.

> 4. Внутри сочетаний ***(не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем*** и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения, запятая не ставится: ...*Посылка весит **не больше чем** восемь килограммов... Задание выполнено **меньше чем** на одну треть...*

Источник: [**Цельные по смыслу выражения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#) (Розенталь).

*Да и сдавать **больше чем через год.*** [Ирина Ратушинская. Одесситы (1998)]

*Итальянец Маркони взял патент на аналогичное изобретенье 2-го июня 1896-го года, то есть **больше чем через год** после демонстрирования...* [Владимир Успенский. «Мы шли на зарево...» (1969) // «Родина», 1996]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.